# Convert List of List to Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column of lists in a spark dataframe.

[image]

How do I convert the arrays to a spark dataframe where each element in the list is a column in the dataframe?

I am new in scala, and I want to use scala to solve it.

For example :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by creating a RDD of rows, creating a schema and using it to convert the RDD to a dataframe.

```
// A seq of seqs
val s = Seq(1 to 6, 1 to 6, 1 to 6)
// Let's create a RDD of Rows
val rdd = sc.parallelize(s).map(Row.fromSeq)

// Let's define a schema based on the first seq of s
val schema = StructType(
    (1 to s(0).size).map(i => StructField("c"+i, IntegerType, true))
)
// And let's finally create the dataframe
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show

// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// | c1| c2| c3| c4| c5| c6|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
// |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe as mentioned in the question with array column as

```
root
 |-- features: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

then you can use following logic

```
val finalCols = Array("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
finalCols.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(df){(tempdf, c) => tempdf.withColumn(c._1, col("features")(c._2))}.select(finalCols.map(col): _*).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |c4 |c5 |c6 |c7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|0  |45 |63 |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|0  |0  |0  |85 |0  |69 |0  |
|0  |89 |56 |0  |0  |0  |0  |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Or you can use a udf function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def splitArrayUdf = udf((features: Seq[Int]) => testCaseClass(features(0), features(1), features(2), features(3), features(4), features(5), features(6)))

df.select(splitArrayUdf(col("features")).as("features")).select(col("features.*")).show(false)
```

which should give you the same the result

I hope the answer is helpful